# Angular Error encountered resolving symbol values stattically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'toastr'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-services, toastr

I am using angular-cli to create an Angular 4 app.

I want to make use of the toastr, so I install the toastr plugin using npm and configure it as shown in the code below.

When running the app, everything works fine. But when I run 'ng build prod', I get the exception below.

How can I resolve this issue? Any idea please?

Thanks

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'toastr'. Consider
>   exporting the symbol (position 35:13 in the original .t s file),
>   resolving symbol AppModule in
>   D:/Projects/afundamentals/src/app/app.module.ts

- Create a new typescript file 'toastr.service.ts' as follows:

```html
   import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';
    export let TOASTR_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('toastr'); // TOASTR_TOKEN is an object
    export interface Toastr {
      success (msg: string, title?: string): void;
      info (msg: string, title?: string): void;
      warning (msg: string, title?: string): void;
      error (msg: string, title?: string): void;
    }
```

- Then, in the 'app.module.ts' I add the following:

```html
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { TOASTR_TOKEN, JQUERY_TOKEN, Toastr } from './common/index';

// declaring the global object toastr and optionally assigning a type of Toastr
declare let toastr : Toastr;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [ 
    ...
    { provide: TOASTR_TOKEN, useValue: toastr },
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Did you fixed it?